# How to extend Customizer payload sent when 'Save & Publish' is triggered

Tags: theme-customizer

By default, customized sent the below payload when the `Save & Publish` button is clicked.

```
wp_customize:on
theme:twentysixteen
customized:{"header_color[primary]":"345"}
nonce:d2a36386d3
action:customize_save
```

Is there a way i can extend the payload to include custom data to be posted?

Refereence: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L3425

Comment: What kind of data and where do you get it from (static?) and what are you going to do with it? Is it meant for all control sections? The more relevant info you give, it's more likely that someone can point you in the right direction ;-)

Comment: I need to pass a unique id which will be used control settings I.e $wp_customizet->add_settings(). I want the control settings to be unique by appending the ID that will be POSTed by customizer appended to the ID.

Comment: If you go and bother the whole wordpress universe, the minimum you should do is have a more coherent question than "I want to do something with the customizer". What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I have tried all tricks possible. Trust me I know my onions. If only the customizer triggers event say after saving is completed, I could have listen to the event and pass in the ID via Ajax post.

Comment: well, customizer do trigger an event after save, `customize_save_after`

Comment: I know about that. That's on the server side. I meant an even that is triggered when the save() method is called in the client side. See the reference link I pasted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkeypatch the `wp.customize.previewer.query` method:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_add_inline_script( 'customize-controls', '(function ( api ) {
        api.bind( "ready", function () {
            var _query = api.previewer.query;

            api.previewer.query = function () {
                var query = _query.call( this );
                query.foo = "bar";
                return query;
            };
        });
    })( wp.customize );'
    );
});
```

This will ensure the script runs immediately after `customize-controls.js` in the markup - note that `wp_add_inline_script` will wrap your JS within `<script />` tags, no need to do it yourself.

Comment: Hey @TheDeadMedic, you rock. This fixed my problem. Thanks so much.